# SEO and Subdomains (Rails Apps)

Tags: seo, subdomain

Let's say I have the following subdomain to my root (mydomain.com): blog.mydomain.com.

Does Google treat the subdomain separately from the root from an SEO perspective?

Is it better to use mydomain.com/blog so that I'm optimizing my root page?

Is there an best-practice RoR approach to rectifying sub-optimization issues presented by the use of subdomains?

Comment: This is not really Rails or programming related.

Comment: Try [here](http://www.seomoz.org/learn-seo/domain) for a description of how they are treated by Google/Bing. Full disclosure I work here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SEO is pretty complicated and changes all the time.

A subdomain will generally be treated as a separate domain for SEO purposes. So whether to place it in a subdirectory or not depends on your overall SEO goals.